# In the following sentences, are the commas in the right place?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> *"Ideas such as the FM modulation, in which the information is put in the frequency of a carrier signal, and doing experiments, for instance, implementing the QAM  algorithm in the electronics lab received my attention."*

I think the comma after "for instance" should be after "lab". Am I right?

Comment: What do you think? What research have you done? You must show research in order to get help.

Comment: does it really matter ?

Comment: Yes it does. This site is a resource, not a personal problem solver. You have to show research of a problem, not just ask it. Specifically, which part of the sentence do you feel is wrong and why?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what is being said. Can you post more of the excerpt or a link to the original?

Comment: I completed the sentences

Comment: I think your opinion is partially correct. I think the sentence doesn't need any commas removed but would benefit from having one added after *lab*. "For instance" and "for example"-styled phrases and their commas can be finicky. Commas were never my strong suit, though.

Comment: I want to use this sentence in an academic writing so I think it is necessary to use commas correctly, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: So, according to what you said, if I add one comma after "lab" is it more convenient for the reader to understand my opinion?

Comment: In my opinion, yes. Try reading [this page](http://www.myenglishteacher.net/forexample.html).

Answer (score 2):

Your core statement is **Ideas received my attention.**

You could legitimately expand this to *Ideas such as FM modulation received my attention.*

All your other clauses are extraneous pieces of information which can be removed without altering the core meaning of the sentence. As such, each of these nonrestrictive clauses should be anchored by commas if they represent a new idea.

However, "doing experiments" has nothing to do with "[i]deas", so your sentence is confusing and needs to be rewritten rather than connected with a conjunction.

Here's what I'd do if death is not an option:

**Ideas such as FM modulation and QAM algorithms receive my attention.**

Any attempt to combine an action with an "idea" is inherently flawed.

However, if you must, (and you are correct):

**Both ideas--such as FM modulation, in which the information is embedded into a carrier wave--and doing experiments, for instance, implementing the
 QAM algorithm in the electronics lab, received my attention.**

Comment: The "and" before "doing" is separating 2 things:1- ideas 2- doing experiments, so ideas and doing experiments received my attention. Is it wrong ?

Comment: There would have to be a comma or an em-dash before *such.*  As written, *doing experiments* is clustered with ideas. See my last example.

Comment: Can I use em-dash in an academic writing?

Comment: Absolutely. The journal or thesis committee can always tell you to change it. You're aiming for comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

> "Ideas such as the FM modulation, in which the information is put in the frequency of a carrier signal, and doing experiments, for instance, implementing the QAM algorithm in the electronics lab received my attention."

I would change it to:

> Ideas relating to FM modulation -- in which information is put in the frequency of the carrier signal -- as well as experiments conducted in the electronics lab relating to QAM algorithms, had/have(context) caught my attention.